# Permission denied: writing a udev rule to to a test file in /etc/udev/rules.d/

Tags: permissions, sudo, udev, permission-denied

An Ubuntu 16.04 udev rule is defined:

```
target='SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Metrologic Scanner", GROUP:="username"'
```

Command to append a rule to test udev file fails:

```
sudo echo $target > /etc/udev/rules.d/test.txt
```

What must be done to overcome the response \ error:

> bash: /etc/udev/rules.d/test.txt: Permission denied

Examples and explanations are highly appreciated: thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this instead and it will work

```
echo "$target" | sudo tee --append /etc/udev/rules.d/test.txt
```

`tee` command with `--append` (shortly `-a`) option appends the echoed string to the specified file, nothing is overwritten.  `tee` also writes to `STDOUT` which can be redirected to `/dev/null` if desired

Another way to do this is

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "$target" > /etc/udev/rules.d/test.txt'
```

but I do recommend sticking with the first example, because `echo "$target"` will be run without root privileges

Comment: It would be helpful \ constructive \ good if each solution had an explanation and the why of the recommendation.   Selected as accepted answer.